# Object oriented design for a Tree

Tags: java, object-oriented, tree

I am implementing a Tree in Java. It must be easy to add a new type of tree e.g. Binary tree and Tertiary tree. Each node can have at least one value. It must be easy to make a new type of node and make a tree of that node.

```
interface Node<T> {

    T getVal();

    boolean equals(Node<T> node);

    String toString();
}
```

```java
interface Tree<T extends Node> {
    boolean addNode(T node);

    boolean removeNode(T node);

    String toString();
}
```

```java
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> implements Node<T> {

    T value;
    BinaryTreeNode<T> firstChild, secondChild;

    BinaryTreeNode(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        firstChild = null;
        secondChild = null;
    }

    public T getVal() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean equals(Node<T> node) {
        return this.value.equals(node.getVal());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "" + value;
    }

    boolean setFirstChild(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) {
        firstChild = node;
        return true;
    }

    BinaryTreeNode<T> getFirstChild() {
        return firstChild;
    }

    boolean setSecondChild(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) {
        secondChild = node;
        return true;
    }

    BinaryTreeNode<T> getSecondChild() {
        return secondChild;
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.*;

public class BinaryTree<T extends BinaryTreeNode> implements Tree<T> {

BinaryTreeNode root;

    BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean addNode(T node) {

        if(root == null) {
            root = node;
        } else {
            addToLast(root, node);
        }

        return true;
    }

    boolean addToLast(BinaryTreeNode root, T node) {

        Deque<BinaryTreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        queue.addLast(root);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            BinaryTreeNode cur = queue.pollFirst();

            if(cur.getFirstChild() == null) {
                cur.setFirstChild(node);
                break;
            } else if(cur.getSecondChild() == null) {
                cur.setSecondChild(node);
                break;
            } else {
                queue.addLast(cur.getFirstChild());
                queue.addLast(cur.getSecondChild());
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean removeNode(BinaryTreeNode node) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public String toString() {

        Deque<BinaryTreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        if(root == null) {
            System.out.println("root is null");
            return "";
        }

        StringBuffer ans = new StringBuffer("");
        queue.addLast(root);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            BinaryTreeNode cur = queue.pollFirst();
            ans.append(" " + cur);

            if(cur.getFirstChild() != null)
                queue.addLast(cur.getFirstChild());

            if(cur.getSecondChild() != null)
                queue.addLast(cur.getSecondChild());

        }

        return ans.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        BinaryTree<BinaryTreeNode> btree = new BinaryTree<>();

        BinaryTreeNode<Integer> node1 = new BinaryTreeNode<>(1);
        btree.addNode(node1);

        System.out.println(btree);
    }
}
```

Following this design pattern, I think it is easier to implement different types of binary trees like binary search tree, heap, red-black tree, etc. Also, one can easily add more information to a node while implementing own implementation of tree.

Is this a good design?

Comment: I don't understand what effort, if any, you have made to design this code to support other types of trees in the future.

Comment: For example, while implementing BinarySearchTree, I will just have to extend BinaryTree and override addNode and removeNode methods.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

But you'll probably need some explanation to believe me.

---

The whole `Node` thing you got there should be internal information to the Tree class, not part of the type. Let's look at the following example method to show why it's a bad idea:

```
private static void addARandomNumber(Tree<Node<Number>> tree) {
    int randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();
    Node<Number> = new ... ???
    tree.addNode(node);
}
```

What class should we use to create a new `Node` here?

Had the `Node` been completely internal to the `Tree` implementation then the interface would look like this:

```
interface Tree<T> {
    boolean add(T node);

    boolean remove(T node);

    String toString();
}
```

And now we can also write the add random number method easily:

```
private static void addARandomNumber(Tree<Number> tree) {
    int randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();
    tree.add(randomNumber);
}
```

---

I also got a feeling that forcing some ordering on T, as required in most search trees, will be rather hard in your current design. But that might just be because I didn't really try it myself yet.

Defining the type of the search tree correctly would probably work, but I expect some type erasure issues with the `addNode` and `removeNode` methods.